# Exception running kafka-console-producer.sh (0.8.1.1)

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying out the kafka-console-producer.sh. I type something to the console and hit enter and I get tons of stack traces to the console like this. Appreciate any pointers.

The command to launch the producer is:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:2181 --topic test
```

Then I type some string and hit enter and see the following in the console.

```
[2014-11-24 15:27:36,022] ERROR fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(test)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:2181)] failed (kafka.utils.Utils$)
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(test)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:localhost,port:2181)] failed
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:167)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:46)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:104)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:87)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:66)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:44)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.read(Utils.scala:376)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readFrom(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:54)
    at kafka.network.Receive$class.readCompletely(Transmission.scala:56)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readCompletely(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:29)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:74)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:71)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:112)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:53)
    ... 12 more
```

I see a warning on the zookeeper console as well:

```
WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

I used the following to setup my topic:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test
```

and I am able to list my topic:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `broker-list` argument is pointing to Zookeeper instead of the actual broker.
The proper usage would be:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

assuming your broker runs on port `9092` (default).

You can refer [here](https://kafka.apache.org/08/quickstart.html) for more information (your issue is described in `Step 4: Send some messages`)

Comment: Can we configure this port 9092 on which broker runs? I could not found corresponding documentation for doing that.

Comment: @Vinit89, yes, it's in `config/server.properties` called `port`

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are starting your consumer in a wrong way. If you will check the [official documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart), you can see that you have to:

start Zookeper

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

start Kafka

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

create a topic

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

start producing messages for a topic

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

**Notice the difference:** you are connecting to zookeper (port 2181) you need to connect to a broker (port 9092)