# Kafka console producer Error in Hortonworks HDP 2.3 Sandbox

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

I have searched it all over and couldn't find the error.
I have checked [This Stackoverflow Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115709/exception-running-kafka-console-producer-sh-0-8-1-1) but it is not the problem with me

1. I have started a zookeeper server

   [image]

Command to start server was

```
 bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

2. Then I SSH into VM by using Putty and started kafka server using

   $ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
3. Then I created Kafka Topic and when I  **list** the topic, it appears.
   [image]
4. Then I opened another putty and started kafka-console-producer.sh and typed any message (even enter) and get this long repetitive exception.
   [image]
   [image]

Configuration files for zookeeper.properties, server.properties, kafka-producer.properties are as following (respectively)
[image]

[image]

[image]

The version of Kafka i am running is 8.2.2. something as I saw it in kafka/libs folder.
**P.S.** I get no messages in consumer.

Can any body figure out the problem?
The tutorial I was following was [This][9]

[8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfwvh.png)http://%60http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Zookeeper_Kafka_single_node_single_broker_cluster.php%60

Comment: Are you sure the Kafka server has started properly? Being able to get the list of topics doesn't confirm that, as that happens via ZK. I'd take a look at the server logs, if there's anything suspicious there.

Comment: I found that In GUI settings of Kafka the kafka listener is on 6667 port and I am using --broker-list localhost:9092. I did some more digging and found that in server.properties file it is 9092 so when I run Kafka from console it runs fine. But when I run it from GUI it crashes

Answer (score 5):

On the hortonworks sandbox have a look at the server configuration:

```
$ less /etc/kafka/conf/server.properties
```

In my case it said

```
...
listeners=PLAINTEXT://sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667
...
```

This means you have to use the following command to successfully connect with the console-producer

```
$ cd /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --broker-list sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667
```

It won't work, if you use `--broker-list 127.0.0.1:6667` or `--broker-list localhost:6667` . See also http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/configure_kafka.html

To consume the messages use

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Comment: I am on HDP 3.0.1, this saved my ass,  thanks, now I can read Kafka topics from a Java client on my host machine ( Windows 10 ), while HDP running inside Virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question that you are using HDP 2.3 and for that when you are running **Console-Producer** 
You need to provide **sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667** in **Broker-list**.

Please use the same while running **Console-Consumer**.

Please let me know in case still you face any issue.

Comment: I run kafka broker listening on port 9092, can I ping it using **ping localhost:9092**?

Comment: Just type command hostname on your vm and whatever hostname you get use that rather than localhost.

Comment: So I just managed to send/receive messages internally(thanks to you). But  now I try to send messages from my host OS using java it throws same error(that server not found or retried 3 times). I learned that it problem with the advertise.host.name property in _server.properties_ . Now I have updated the server. properties file with leates code. Kindly help me how to allow kafka server to accept messages from outside

Comment: Hi @Bector can you plz look at this [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602107/accessing-kafka-in-sandbox-from-host-os-after-trying-every-solution)

Comment: Tried to answer your question, please refer the same link to see.

Answer (score 0):

Within Kafka internally there is a conversation that goes on between both producers and consumers (clients) and the broker (server).  During those conversations clients often ask the server for the address of a server broker that's managing a particular partition.  The answer is always a fully-qualified host name.  Without going into specifics if you ever refer to a broker with an address that is not that broker's fully-qualified host name there are situations when the Kafka implementation runs into trouble.

Another mistake that's easy to make, especially with the Sandbox, is referring to a broker by an address that's not defined to the DNS.  That's why every node on the cluster has to be able to address every other node in the cluster by fully-qualified host name.  It's also why, when accessing the sandbox from another virtual image running on the same machine you have to add sandbox.hortonworks.com to the image's hosts file.