# Accessing kafka in sandbox from Host OS (after trying every solution)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

Cnsider me a noob.
I have read all the issues on stack overflow and tried for one day but the solution just do not click to me. PLEASE Help me specifically to my SETTINGS and CODE(because I have tried all possibilities from same issues on stack overflow - )

**This is my Producer.properties file**

[image]

**This is my server.properties file**

[image]

**This is my code**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("metadata.broker.list", "sandbox.hortonworks.com:9093");
//props.put("zk.connect", "sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String> (topic1,"ccccccccc");


System.out.println(data);
producer.send(data);
```

**This is the eclipse output**

```
KeyedMessage(tweeter,null,ccccccccc)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Samhash**, as per my understanding **advertised.host.name** should be an IP address which is pingable from your local machine. To your local machine, I don't think so **sandbox.hortonworks.com** will be understood or you may have to make an entry for this host in your local machine.
Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well in Hit and Trail strategy I finally Caught the problem.

There are 4 properties in server.properties file
*port*, *host.name*, *advertised host name* and *advertised port*

And 1 property in Producer.properties file
*metadata.broker.list*

Make sure that broker.list is same as advertised.host.name:advertised.port

Comment host.name property as it doesn't effect If advertised host name is given.

I simply got ip of my sandbox using `ifconfig` command and then put that IP with 9092 port in both properties and it worked.